# command 'touch database/database.sqlite' does not work

Tags: php, database, laravel, sqlite, command

To create a new SQLite database, I used this command 
`touch database/database.sqlite` on Laravel 6.2.0

It shows the error

> touch is not recognized as an internal or external command.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

touch command dose not exist for windows you can use git bash to use touch command or you can Download & Install SQLite on Windows https://www.guru99.com/download-install-sqlite.html then go to C:\sqlite

```
cd C:\sqlite
```

then make you'r database with this command

```
sqlite3 databaseName.db
```

or

```
database.sqlite
```

there is another link you can use https://www.guru99.com/sqlite-database.html
but i suggest to use git bash